# How to use before_filter/before_action in action cable channels?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, before-filter, channel, actioncable

I'm trying to use before_filter/before_action in the action cable channels but server responding 'undefined method before_filter'.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [`on_subscribe` and `on_unsubscribe`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/actioncable/ActionCable/Channel/Callbacks/ClassMethods#on_subscribe-instance_method)?

Comment: No, but before calling any method in the channel after subscription, I want to use before_action/before_filter but its not working in the channel.rb file.  Is there any action in the actioncable?

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to achieve with this?

Answer (score 0):

Here I find out the solution:

After subscription, use "after_subscribe" to call another method.

Comment: before_subscribe  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionCable/Channel/Callbacks.html#method-i-before_subscribe